# Set of ALL holomorphic homomorphisms of the multiplicative group (ℂ*, ×)

Tags: complex-analysis

##### Question:

I need to find the set $S$ of all the holomorphic homomorphisms of the multiplicative group (ℂ*, ×). That is, the set $S$ containing all the holomorphic functions $G$ satisfying $\forall x,y \in \mathbb C^*, G(xy) = G(x)G(y)$.

##### Draft:

The conditions over $G$ are super restrictive, so my intuition is that these kinds of functions are not common. I know that all the power functions are included in the set $S$. Now, I am trying to prove that $S$ is the set of all the power functions (or not).

---

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the values a homomorphism takes on the unit circle $\mathbb{U}$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! ($\mathbb U$, ×) is the largest bounded subgroup of (ℂ*, ×). All bounded subgroups of $\mathbb C^*$ are included in $\mathbb U$. We know that ($G(\mathbb U)$, ×) is a subgroup of (ℂ*, ×) because $G$ is a homomorphism of (ℂ*, ×). So, if $G(\mathbb U)$ is bounded, $G(\mathbb U)$ is included in $\mathbb U$, right?

Comment: Yes, but you need to find some stronger facts. Another hint: remark that if $G ∈ S$, then $G(-1)^2 = 1$, so the possible values for $G$ are $1$ and $-1$. How can you generalize this to other roots of unity?

Comment: Aw thanks so much! $\forall n \in \mathbb N, \forall u \in \mathbb U_n: G(u)^n = G(u^n) = G(1) = 1$, so $ \forall n \in \mathbb N, \forall u \in \mathbb U_n: G(u) \in \mathbb U_n$, correct?